# How to declare random value from array with a loop?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have a program which outputs random animals through a loop. My goal is to get one animal to be randomly outputted by the loop. I've tried declaring array[0] - array[4] outside the loop as well and it still does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
String[] array= new String[4]; 

        //output random animals
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[0] = "Dogs!"
            array[1] = "Rabbits!"
            array[2] = "Cats!";
            array[3] = "Fish!";
            array[4] = "Horse!";
            itsATextArea.setText(array[i] + "\n");  //output
        }
```

Edit: The error pops up as...

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
```

Comment: You are trying to put 5 animals in an array of size 4....

Answer (score 3):

Here is the fixed code:

```
String[] array= new String[5];
array[0] = "Dogs!";
array[1] = "Rabbits!";
array[2] = "Cats!";
array[3] = "Fish!";
array[4] = "Horse!";

//output random animals
itsATextArea.setText(array[(int) (Math.random() * array.length)]);  //output
```

1. There are 5 elements in the array, not 4.
2. You should fill your array outside of the loop, because otherwise you are filling it each time the loop iterates which is useless. You only want to fill it once.
3. There is nothing in your code that has anything to do with randomness. I added the randomness in the last line. `Math.random()` returns a random number from `0` to `1`, so multiplying it by the length returns a number from `0` to `length - 1`. Then I casted it to an `int` so it's not a decimal value.

Also, there's a much easier way of initializing the array:

```
String[] array = {"Dogs!", "Rabbits!", "Cats!", "Fish!", "Horse!"};
```

Comment: I changed it to five, still the exact same error pops up as in the question, the only difference being "4" is now "5"

Comment: @user2407152 What did you change to 5? The length of the array?

Comment: @user2407152 And everything else is the same? Try copy/pasting the code in my answer to your program.

Comment: I have copy and pasted everything, would you like me to edit the question to show you what I have changed? (Though it's the exact same so nothing surprising...)

Comment: This is the error...Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5

Comment: @user2407152 On what line are you getting the error? It works for me, see [this link](http://ideone.com/zElPFL)

Comment: I'm not sure if this makes a difference, but this is a GUI and all this code is under "actionPerformed" button, I will try that link though

Comment: ...I have the error, a most subtile dumb error on my part... -.- I thank you for helping me though for correcting the randomness! =)

Answer (score 1):

You have nothing that would make for any randomness in your code. Take a look at using [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html). There are loads of examples on the site.

Answer (score 1):

```
array[0] = "Dogs!"
array[1] = "Rabbits!"
array[2] = "Cats!";
array[3] = "Fish!";
array[4] = "Horse!";

itsATextArea.setText((int)array[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)]);
```

There is no need for the for loop.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Oh shit, I thought this was a JavaScript question.

Answer (score 0):

You would do it like this:

```
import java.util.Random;
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(array.length);

System.out.println("my animal is" + array[randomInt]);
```